# Definitions of continuity in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to sovle the below problem.

> Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f$ be a function $X \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Give your own definition of continuity for $f$ from Calculus. Endow $X$ with the metric induced from any of the induced metrics from Examples (iii), (iv), or (v). Show that your definition coincides with the general metric space definition given above.

> The examples that are referenced are:
>
> (iii) The metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\rho(x,y) = ((x_1 - y_1)^2 + \ldots + (x_n - y_n)^2)^{1/2}$.
>
> (iv) The metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\rho(x,y) = \max\limits_{i = 1, \ldots, n} |x_i - y_i|$.
>
> (v) The metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\rho(x,y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i|$.

I think the definition of continuity "from calculus" that the problem references is surely the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, but with the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. So the definition of $f$ being continuous at $y$ is:
$$
\forall y \in X, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in X, |y-x| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon. 
$$
With the way that I've defined it, I've already endowed $X$ with the metric from example (iii), so I'm not sure what else I need to do at that point. The definitions are surely equivalent. I could also replace $||$ with any arbitrary distance function that induces a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the definition would be analagous.

Can someone help me make sense of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your $\epsilon-\delta$ definition you have actually defined uniform continuity. To define continuity you need to take the $\forall x\in X$ at least one spot to the left.

Hint: draw the unit balls of each of the 3 metrics. Do this in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where it's easy. As you say, definition 3 is the usual one from Calculus, and you will get a circle. Can you see what you get for the other two? Once you do, you just need to show that every ball of one metric can be contained in a ball of the other metric.

Comment: Does that mean that by "coincides," the problem means that the three metrics induce the same topology?

Comment: @JohnT I think they mean that a function $f(x)$ is continuous under one of the metrics if and only if it is continuous under any of the other metrics. Indeed as you say this follows from the metrics all inducing the same topology.